# Hazelcast IMap not available in JMX on startup

Tags: jmx, hazelcast

I am trying to add monitoring for a hazelcast map to Nagios. Now I face the issue that the IMap entry in JMX is not available before the first usage of this map (get/set values)

Is there any option to initialize this during hazelcast startup.

The map is configured as follows

```
<map name="myMap">
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="USED_HEAP_SIZE">256</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    <map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="EAGER" />
</map>
```

I already tried to add map-store eager loading but this also did not fixed the issue:

```
<map name="myMap">
    ...
    <map-store enabled="true" initial-mode="EAGER" />
</map>
```

The JMX path which I try to access is

```
com.hazelcast:instance=_hzInstance_1_dev,type=IMap,name=myMap
```

How can I configure the map in such a way that the JMX values are always available.